# Google App Engine Error: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Combined version and service (module) name is too long

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

I am working on one application whose UI part is written in React and redux, middle layer using golang and it is using Google Cloud Datastore as NoSQL service. I have to deploy this service using drone.io. When I try to deploy my service, I get below error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Combined version and service (module) name is too long.  The combined length must be less than 48 characters.
```

My front end service name is too short(adlib-rules-mgr). Other details are as below-

```
descriptor:      [/drone/src/github.com/nytm/adtech-adlib-web/app.yaml]
source:          [/drone/src/github.com/nytm/adtech-adlib-web]
target project:  [nyt-adtech-dev]
target service:  [adlib-rules-mgr]
target version:  [5e4890f35a4f21a08853298d362f7f68b26a945e]
target url:      [https://adlib-rules-mgr-dot-nyt-adtech-dev.appspot.com]
```

Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong and how this issue can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the Combined version and service name should be 48 characters maximum. Yours, "adlib-rules-mgr" and "5e4890f35a4f21a08853298d362f7f68b26a945e" add up to 55 characters and thus is rejected.

It seems your drone.io setting uses the Github commit number as version name for your App Engine app. I'm not familiar with drone.io myself but you should set a shorter name for your version.

Comment: Hi you are right as the version string length is of 40 characters and maximum length allowed was of 48 characters long, I changed my service name "ad-rule" making a whole string of length 47. This worked for me, however, I don't know how drone settings uses Github commit number and how can I change it to make string shorter.